# Share file over wifi on Window Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, sharing

Is it feasible to develope an app which has ability to share a file to another window phone 7 device via bluetooth or wifi ? what i want to share is an image, video or music.
I just want to know is it possible or not, so if u know that please help me, very high appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently such APIs are not available for WP7. I hope they make it available in future releases. For information regarding bluetooth read the following article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449475

Answer (score 0):

As SplashID APP is doing same thing using WIFI. We can use TCP sockets to implement file share feature. we need to send packets in small chunk.

Regards
Mahantesh